# Can panpsychism be scientifically tested?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Panpsychism, in the general sense of everything in nature has some sort of consciousness (and I know, this is highly dependent on the way we define consciousness, but I want to talk about panpsychism in the general term, so, if it's ok, I'll let the answers to determine what definition of consciousness is used). Sometimes it's defined as multiple levels of consciousness, sometimes as one consciousness acting "behind" everything.

My question would be, can panpsychism, in any way, have some scientific (/empirical) testable meaning? In other words, is this line of thought worth exploring in science?

I know panpsychism is mostly metaphysical, and the idea of metaphysical to be tested in the science realms is often rejected, but maybe some aspects of it can be.

Comment: One problem is that even if we can come up with a widely-agreed-upon definition of 'consciousness', there's the issue of how 'fast' a given consciousness is. How do we know that, for example, the universe isn't 'talking' to us right now, but at a rate too slow for us to perceive? That it saying "Hello!" is a process that takes dozens of human lifetimes to complete?

Comment: It would be arrogant for us to assume that the metabolic rate of humans universally defines the rate of communication between conciousnesses, but it does somewhat impose limits on hypotheses testable via observations.

Comment: At this point nothing in particular seems to be on offer, although it is conceivable that phenomenal consciousness might have empirical consequences. Even if it does not the idea may have legitimate theoretical uses. After all, efficient causation also has no empirical consequences, as Hume eloquently explained, all we observe is one event following another, not the "causing" of it, yet it is widely used to organize our theories around causal laws.

Comment: I can't speak for the literature, but I find approaches like panpsychism to be very effective at pinning down what sorts of definitions of consciousness science might be permitted to admit.  The Integrated Information Theory of Consciousness (IIT) is one such example.  It's defined in a way which permits some testing, but defines consciousness on a gradient, rather than discrete levels, so it could be adapted to panpsychism easily.

Comment: No theory of consciousness can be tested in the natural sciences. It is not an empirical phenomenon. For science consciousness is a theoretical entity, unprovable and untestable. Quite why scientists so often fail to see this might be a good question for the forum.

Comment: @PeterJ it will, and that's something I thought of asking but as Conifold often say, I simply don't really know about the scientific community, so asking this question will assume that it's a known issue which might be untrue. But let's assume consciousness itself is really an untestable phenomenon *on its own*. Maybe we can see a causal effects related to it (in the psychological way perhaps), and research from that point?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - We can do this, yes, and it's exactly what we do in the sciences. But we should not confuse this with empiricism. For the natural sciences consciousness is a flying spaghetti monster, as more than one philosopher has pointed out. I've spent many years following scientific consciousness studies so am not speaking casually.

Comment: @PeterJ Simulations are great sources of evidence across the sciences. We know if we could simulate the whole human brain, we should gain insights into mechanisms maybe more, & The Human Brain Project is doing that. Consciousness may or may not be testable depend n the model for how it occurs. You don't have to go with Turing, and ignore subjective experience. Issues around qualia may be for philosophy only, of course.

Comment: @CriglCragl - Okay, but I don't understand how there's any 'might' about it.

Comment: @PeterJ If consciousness wasn't empirical you wouldn't know about it.

Comment: How would you tell complete (100%) conditioning of something with a brain from a natural law? This assumes however that something with a conscience can be conditioned. If you take a rock falling down for example, how are you going to refute the hypothesis that it has been conditioned to do so just before humans have started observing it.

Comment: @Peter J Brain transfers if possible would allow empirical qualia gathering

Comment: @CriglCragl - Qualia are not empirical phenomena. 'Empirical' refers to sensory data,

Comment: @Peter J We can potentially know what it's _like_ to be a bat, through simulations, brain scanning, and in the future thought scanning and transfer. We may not be able to know what it's like to be a particular bat, from it's perspective of not having known anything else, but that is just pedantry. We have reason to expect brains to be universal Turing machines, capable of running the thoughts of other brains of equivalent or less processing power

Comment: @user 20253 you are incorrect. I recommend that you acquaint yourself with the literature.

Answer (score 3):

[Gregory Matloff](http://www.gregmatloff.com/Edge%20Science%20Matloff-ES29.pdf) has been attempting to scientifically test panpsychism by using the anomaly in stellar motions in Parenego’s discontinuity. Certain types of stars do not follow their expected paths based on gravitation theory.

One could attempt to find panpsychism by looking for agents. One looks for agents where determinism breaks down and one is forced to consider randomness.  Given randomness if it is not uniform, such as flipping a coin, something more needs to be explained.  One explanation is that an agent is present.  So testing panpsychism involves looking for non-uniform randomness.  Whether anyone accepts this as science would be influenced by social mood more than metaphysics.  At the quantum level this randomness is present and could be used as a justification for agency and hence panpsychism although one can easily ignore the whole issue.

Comment: Panpsychism, absurd as it is, at least does not presume everything has *physical agency*. And on the topic of quantum mechanics, one must certainly avoid the trap of [quantum mechanics and consciousness are both weird and therefore equivalent](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3).

Comment: @Veedrac It is good to note that panpsychism needs to distinguish between what has agency and what doesn't.  There will be different theories based on what the theory claims has agency. One can cover up that agency by talking about randomness as the graphic story that you linked said, "classical events have probabilities and quantum events have amplitudes". There are multiple ways to build a theory on data. The most data can do is attempt to falsify a theory and even then a theory's supporters can modify it to slip out of a falsification.

Comment: @FrankHubeny correct, I just read an article in relation to panpsychism, and for every little specific distinction, there's a philosopher who built an entire theory around that. It's funny, but it's very important work.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss David Skrbina's _Panpsychism in the West_ provides a survey of the ideas and philosophers.

Comment: @FrankHubeny thanks. I've read Chalmers' Idealism and the Mind-body Problem which summed up some of those nicely, I'll definitely read Skrbina.

Answer (score 2):

The brain is an instrument already suited to the problem of measuring and inspecting consciousness. We know this to be true because people are aware of consciousness. Consciousness is thus observable, just like any other physical property, and it is obviously bidirectionally causal given that consciousness varies by social environment and whether you stick a steel rod through someone's head.

Some people hypothesize a separate aspect of consciousness that is causally unrelated to physical reality; this allows for things like philosophical zombies. However, we can dismiss this argument (stronger variants too) on scientific principles: if consciousness was acausal (or unidirectionally causal) there would be no evolutionary pressure for it, so it would have to arise purely by coincidence. By the theory's proponents' own admission, any arguments you hear for it can *at best* be true by coincidence, since if it were true any argument for it would be uncorrelated with it. Finally we note that this argument wouldn't even solve the problems it purports to; any such causal model in which this true consciousness lives would be just as susceptible to the hard problem as the original universe.

Since fairly basic logical reasoning shows us that consciousness is a physically observable, causal system, we can conclude that studying the nature by which the brain interacts with consciousness at least plausibly leads us to an understanding of the processes and systems which underlie conscious experience. This leads to an understanding of panpsychism the same way local studies of gravity and local observations of light fields (through telescopes) have allowed us to discover black holes. With high likelihood we can apply the same understanding and inspective capability that applies to our brain to other, non-brain systems.

Comment: +1 The "bidirectionally causal" aspect of our own consciousness is interesting. Do you have a reference or link to more information?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to panpsychism, when you claim that consciousness is purely physical.

Comment: @FrankHubeny I don't know who to credit for these ideas, sorry. I do know David Chalmers admitted to most of those, despite somehow holding the contrary position: "Because this explanation applies to a zombie, the existence of consciousness will play no essential role in the explanation." (aka. Should consciousness be acausal, we cannot have evidence that it acausal.) Why he goes from demonstrating that he cannot possible know consciousness is acausal, to certainty that he does, I cannot say.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Only the last paragraph is an answer to your question; the first two just preempt likely objections, like "we can't just measure consciousness because it's acausal."

Comment: @Veedrac so the idea is that physical observation will lead to mental findings? I'm not sure how one could produce the other, and am also not sure about the comparison made to light fields and black holes, and they are both physical, not compared to the first case. It'll hit the same problem as the classic macro-idealism (Chalmers) emergent problem - how can physical lead to mental.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss The analogy was just that we don't have direct observations of black holes just as we don't have direct observations of nonhuman consciousness; this doesn't prevent us from making categorical claims about them.

Comment: Regardless of the hard problems (*why* do gravitational laws exist; *why* do systems cause epiphenomenon), we can produce predictive models that generalize to the wanted areas (gravity arises from mass interacting with space-time, so those perturbations in the light field are evidence for black holes; consciousness arises from <these discovered structures>, so <these observations> are evidence for panpsychism).

Comment: @Veedrac hmm.. Interesting. But I'm still not entirely convinced (although I want to be) that this isn't a wider distinction - mental and physical are fundamentally different, they're are two entirely different kinds of phenomenons, so it seems odd that one could be evident to the other (even indirectly). Although that's everyone else's answer too, so this is nothing specific for yours.

Comment: @Yechiam Weiss Are they though? If phenomena are fundamentally informational, the physical is a kind of thought-stuff in the first place. Like the shift from space as a neutral background, to something active

Comment: @CriglCragl so you're saying mental turns to non-mental? That'll hit the emergent problem I stated before. (edit- maybe it's called "constituent problem" and I'm mistaking the both)

Answer (score 1):

It will be when we have a clearer idea how consciousnesses arise.

There are proposals to formulate physics solely in terms of information, which could be described as treating things as constitutec of mind.

Models like the P2P simulation hypothesis make concrete predictions, or at least aimed to explain specific observations https://www.p2p-simulation-hypothesis.com

Pansychism historically has not been a niche view, but the majority view. Materialism seems to have arisen out of dualism and reductionism, given stature by their great success in making it easier to do science. Systems, synergies & holisms are perhaps only in very recent times, on the table for science.

Answer (score 0):

Panpsychism proposes that the fundamental stuff of the universe is matter-consciousness. So it is not metaphysical. Nothing stands behind this fundamental stuff. See Chalmers and Goff, for example. In this interpretation consciousness exists at the quantum level. Quantum entanglement has been suggested as an example of this. So, panpsychism is amenable to experimentation to disprove it. The null hypothesis is that consciousness does not exist at the quantum level. The latest quantum entanglement experiments show entanglement when the entangled particles are separated by 200 km.

Comment: `The latest quantum entanglement experiments show entanglement when the entangled particles are separated by 200 km.` and this is evidence of panpsychism ?

Comment: It is evidence of "spooky action at a distance" as Einstein said. The two entangled particles are aware of one another's status independently of the speed of light. This suggests consciousness at this level. Thus the hypothesis can be tested.

Comment: If most quantum physicists were panpsychists, this might be something. At the moment, though, quantum physics has a history of being easily co-opted by woo, and this feels very much like that. I like panpsychism, personally - I'm not a panpsychist, but I'm open to it - but I just don't think quantum physics has much to do with it at all. `Quantum physics is true, therefor panpsychism is true` doesn't seem to be a completely valid take, at least not at the current point in time. Maybe things will change in the future.

Comment: As a scientist myself, I know that science is not  popularity contest. I think that a paradigm shift is coming. Quantum physics is fundamental to our understanding of the universe, and therefore fundamental to our philosophical understanding. I am sure that things will change in the future. They always do.

Comment: Hi there, gotta say it's rather odd to cite Goff as a supporter of "panpsychism is not metaphysics" when he has clear talks in which he distinguishes metaphysical topics, such as panpsychism v. physicalism, from scientific topics such as quantum theory and the standard model.

Comment: That is my own view. Others obviously differ. The citation is for information about panpsychism generally.  In my view, the fundamental matter-consciousness nature of the universe renders metaphysics redundant. What is your answer? @Yechiam Weiss

Comment: @Yechiam Weiss My answer cites Chalmers and Goff. It also cites evidence from experiments in quantum entanglement. This is not opinion.  I find your comment baffling.